# Is a prior distribution always a random probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian

Let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space and let its probability measure be $P$. In Bayesian statistics, we may wish to define a prior $\mu$ on the space of all such probability measures, say $\mathcal{P}$. Can we say $\mu$ is a random probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$?

For instance, the $k$-dimensional Dirichlet distribution defines a probability measure over a $(k-1)$-dimensional probability simplex $\Delta_k = \{q \in \mathbb{R}^k | \sum_{i=1}^k q_i = 1, q_i \geq 0, i = 1, \ldots, k\}$, which is a set of all probability measures on a finite set $\mathcal{X} = \{1, \ldots, k\}$. In that sense, is $\mu$ a random probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: In the parametric case, when your prior is a measure on some finite dimensional manifold, I suppose you can say the model is a bundle-like object, where the fibers are themselves measure spaces.

Comment: I'm sorry I can not understand this abstraction...Could you provide more details about your comment?

Comment: Well, in the parametric non-Bayesian setting, you just have a family of probability spaces indexed by the parameters, correct? Bayesians put a measure on the parameters, so your "index space" is itself a measure space. This is akin to a vector bundle where you have a family of vector spaces indexed by a manifold. That's all I meant.